# How to Live stream RTMP/RTSP to a WOWZA server on Android

Tags: android, streaming, wowza, broadcasting

I am developing an Android application in which I want to publish as well as stream a video...

What I want is:

My app records a video and that video is sent to the server

The recorded video will be streamed live to another Android device at the same time..

P.S.:

I am using wowza server and RTMP stream. I would like to stream RTMP video (.flv)... If no solution is available, I would like to switch to RTSP and for that also, need a working link to follow.

Are there any suite of classes that make this easy?

Comment: Check this examples-https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples

Answer (score 0):

Using libstreaming you can stream live video to the Wowza server form the android device running Android 4.0(API Level 14),or more recent.

For More details Check this link: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/wiki/Using-libstreaming-with-Wowza-Media-Server

Download the examples from here: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples